# Clarification on what requests use CORS

Tags: cors

[This Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS) lists Stylesheets and Scripts as requests that use CORS.

So let's say I browse to https://www1.example.com using my web browser and I get this HTML back:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://www2.example.com/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www2.example.com/script.js" />
<head>
<body>
    <img src="https://www2.example.com" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Questions:**

1. Will a web browser treat any of the above three requests as a CORS request? Specifically, will a web browser send an `Origin` header with any of those requests?
2. Conversely, will the www2.example.com server need to set an `access-control-allow-origin` header when responding to any of the above three requests?

Comment: 1) none of those embedded resources involve the CORS protocol at all. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access & in particular the *Cross-origin embedding is typically allowed* part & the examples there; the gist of it is: browsers allow cross-origin resources embedded with script src, link rel, img, video, audio, object, embed, and iframe. & no, browsers won’t send the Origin header for those 2) the www2.example.com server will not need to set an access-control-allow-origin header to allow that img src element to work as expected

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  Out of interest, why do you single out the img element in your answer to question 2?

Comment: I didn’t mean to single out just img. They’re qualitatively all the same case. I just ran out of space in the comment to elaborate.